# Image won't center with text-align:center because of a span next to it

Tags: html, css

https://codepen.io/codepen_user_123/pen/yLarYRP

So I have this big number next to it that I want to center. It's inside a span, and I am trying to prevent the span from preventing the image to be exactly in the center of the div, but changing the width of the span to 0% or 100% doesn't seem to do anything. Is there a hack to get this working?

```
<span class="number"style="
    font-size: 40px;
    position:relative;
    left: -125px;
    width: 100%;
    top: -125px;                       
">4 </span>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the parent element's position to `relative` and the element you want to position via `left`, `top`, `right`, `bottom` as `absolute`, and center it with the 50%, 50% and transform: translate "trick":

```html
<div style="
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    
    border-radius: 100px;
">
    <!-- sample circle -->
    <div
      style="
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
      "
    ></div>
    
    <!-- the thing you want to position absolutely -->
    <span class="number"style="
        font-size: 40px;
        position:absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    "
    >
        4
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without absolute? What if I have other elements on my page?

Comment: sorry, I don't think I understand the question -- could you thoroughly clarify (preferably in the original question's description?)